# How to stop reordering in NSFetchResultController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a `UICollectionView` with `NSFetchResultController`. I am sorting the fetch request with an attribute "modifiedDate". If there is any update in the fetched object, the modified date will also get updated which leads to reordering. I do not want the `reordering` to occur in `NSFetchResultController`. Is there any solution available for this?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are organizing your `UICollectionView` by the value of "modifiedDate" property, it might not be a good idea not to reorder if the value gets updated.

What you CAN do is:

1. decide whether the old value of the `"modifiedDate"` property is still good to use. In most cases you only care about the day of modification, not the exact time.
2. update your `UICollectionView` accordingly if the value of 'modifiedDate' property is changed